# Validating user input in C# coming from XAML controls

Tags: c#, beginner, validation, xaml, xamarin

I have page where I am inserting some data into Entry fields. For each Entry I have written in XAML different controls with parameters. One of them is Formated parameter where I am giving a string which I am checking on C# logic code. The problem which I figure out that some one could insert wrong string or string but for example with lower case. How can I improve this code for any wrong input scenarios ?

This is my xaml code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout Padding="7,7,7,7" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0">

      <cv:LabelEntryView x:Name="Name" LabelText="some text 4" ColorBg="White" MaxLength="20" Placeholder="some text 4" Formated="NameValidation" Keyboard="Text" >
      </cv:LabelEntryView>

      <cv:LabelEntryView x:Name="CardNr" LabelText="some text 3" ColorBg="White" MaxLength="20" Placeholder="some text 3" Formated="CardNrValidation" Keyboard="Numeric"  >
      </cv:LabelEntryView>

      <cv:LabelEntryView x:Name="ExpDate" LabelText="some text 2" ColorBg="White" MaxLength="5" Placeholder="some text 2" Formated="ExpDate" Keyboard="Numeric" >
      </cv:LabelEntryView>

      <cv:LabelEntryView x:Name="SecurNr" LabelText="some text" ColorBg="White" MaxLength="3" Placeholder="some text" Keyboard="Numeric" >
      </cv:LabelEntryView>

    </StackLayout>

  </ContentPage.Content>
```

and here is my C# code with if statement checking string:

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Formated == "NameValidation")
            {
                Entry ent = (Entry)sender;
                ToUpper(ent);
            }
            else if (Formated == "CardNrValidation")
            {
                Entry ent = (Entry)sender;
                CardNumberValidation(ent);
            }
            else if (Formated == "ExpDate")
            {
                Entry ent = (Entry)sender;
                ExpDate(ent,e);
            }
}
```

Maybe I have to assign type for each if check? If yes, how can I do it?
Thank you for your reviews.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how it should be done in WPF especially that you are not validating the text but just changing it upper case - you validate only the numeric input.

The *right* way would be to use the [Binding Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx)

This method would allow you to write specialized validators *without* `if`s or `switch`es.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could you switch statement

```
 private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
  Entry ent = (Entry)sender;
  switch((Formated )
  {
   case "NameValidation":
   ToUpper(ent);
   break;

   case "CardNrValidation":
   CardNumberValidation(ent);
   break;

   case "ExpDate":
   ExpDate(ent);
   break;
  }
 }
```

Comment: But all you did is changing `if {} else if{}` statement into `switch`. It's not changing anything really.

Answer (score 0):

C# can switch `string`.

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // If it is not Entry, it would be null
    var ent = sender as Entry;
    if(ent == null) return;
    switch (Formated)
    {
        case "NameValidation":
            ToUpper(ent);
            break;
        case "CardNrValidation":
            CardNumberValidation(ent);
            break;
        case "ExpDate":
            ExpDate(ent, e);
            break;
    }
}
```

However, it is a bit strange than you are not check the condition by parameter. There may be other part of your code can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about wrong data being written in `Formated` property (eg. lower case) you could do some string normalization.

```
private void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Formated))
    {
        return;
    }

    string formatted = Formated.ToUpper();
    /* perform your checks */
}
```

Also if values stored in `Formated` property are known - there is just some set of acceptable values, you could use `enum` and map given string to this `enum` value. This would make your code less error prone, since in your current implementation *you* could mistype some acceptable value in some of your `if` clauses.

Comment: I also think, that enum would be good idea, now I declared `enum FomationType { None, NameValidation, CardNrValidation, ExpDate };` like this, but how can I assign these values in XAML and in C#?